# GCloud win-server 2019 good VM platform for web-app-dev and web-app-hosting?

Tags: windows

I'm new to setting up the environment for a VM for web-app-dev and web-app-hosting for some project goals. I had used a Debian VM, but Linux always stayed too far out of my knowledge to get fluent enough with it.
I have added a Win-Server-2019 VM on GCloud, which is up and running, but not sure if thats a good choice as VM platform for web-app-dev and web-app-hosting at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Only you can decide your platform, your operating system and application stack. It is an organization specific thing with many considerations: how well it solves your problems, dev and ops experience, technical inertia, vendor relations, support lifecycle, cost.

We do not provide advice on platform choice.